# Exception Access Violation during render when modifying material per-frame in script

Tags: python, rendering, materials, scripting

I'm duplicating an object and its material and then modifying the new material per frame. The object exists for ~0.5 seconds and then is destroyed. All of the duplicated objects are stored in a dictionary (this is an attempt to resolve another problem [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/231208/randomizing-particle-behavior/231301)).

Unfortunately I'm getting random Exception Access Violations on lines where I'm accessing the duplicated object or material. See the following code:

```
    material = [x for x in bpy.data.materials if new_bolts[bolt_name][0] in x.name]
    if len(material) > 0:
#        m = material[0]
#        tree = m.node_tree
#        nodes = tree.nodes
#        bolt_group = nodes.get('bolt_group')
#        bolt_length = bolt_group.inputs.get('Bolt Length')
#        if bolt_length:
#            bolt_length.default_value = length
#        else:
#            raise Exception("ERROR, Bolt Length not found!")
        context.collection.objects.get(bolt_name).material_slots[0].material.node_tree.nodes.get('bolt_group').inputs.get('Bolt Length').default_value = length
```

(context is bpy.context passed in as a parameter)

These are two different attempts (commented vs. uncommented); both have resulted in an access violation exception on either `bolt_length.default_value = length` or the uncommented line (I've also gotten them many other places).

The script runs perfectly fine when using the Timeline in the editor (looping many times), as well as with doing the "Viewport Render Animation" option. It's only during a "normal" render that it crashes.

I tried rendering on a single thread, as opposed the auto-detected multiple, but that didn't help.

Does anyone know how I might resolve this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My "solution" to this was to avoid running the script, and instead treat the object as a particle and make my modifications there.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/231301/125759